# JS/jQuery : Best way to get typed characters after '#' in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, hash

**I am creating a smart textarea that needs to recognise a term typed after the '#' symbol.This needs to be able to work for the term CURRENTLY being typed and be able to work for multiple instances of the '#' symbol in a single textarea.**

It is designed to work the same way as Facebook when you type the '@' symbol to tag a person in a post. A drop down list will appear and list items will get filtered depending on the term after the '#' symbol.

This also needs to work if the user were to type a term then amend it later. I understand this complicates things a little.

What is the best way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it helps but here's i small script to find the hashes.
http://jsfiddle.net/aNgVV/

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the keyup event and check what has been entered last like so:

```
       $('#myTextArea').keyup(function () {

            var len = $(this).val().length;

            if ($(this).val().substring(length - 1, 1) == '#') {

                // Do whatever you want to do here

            }

        });
```

**EDIT:**

You are right - you could do it this way instead:

```
$('#myTextArea').keypress(function (e) {

    if (e.which == 222) {

        // do something here

    }

});
```

Comment: That will only work for the last word in the entire string. What if the user goes back to change a hash tag value? The whole function is ruined.

Comment: Yes you are right, I have updated with another method which will solve this problem.

Comment: I am concerned with the storing and amending of existing hash values in a string rather than the capturing of the keypress of a hash key.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at the jQuery UI demo for the Autocomplete widget, specifically the demo for [using a remote datasource with cache](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache). Specifically for the following reasons:

1. It automatically takes care of the drop-down widget you mentioned.
2. It demonstrates how you can populate that drop-down with items based on an AJAX call (which I presume you need).
3. The demo for Autocomplete caching parses the text in the `INPUT` element, as it tries to determine whether or not the value the user is currently typing has already been cached, and reacts accordingly. I assume you can do something similar to check for the `#` types, and to check if a previous `#` tag is being modified as well.

Comment: I'm looking for a more customised solution not restricted by a plugin framework.

Comment: I'll go ahead and argue that you can actually customize the Autocomplete widget very, very flexibly (and since you're using jQuery anyway, why not), which is definitely a treat. Just used it for my own business process and was really happy with it. :) If something like that doesn't suit you, well, to each his own I guess. :D

Answer (score 1):

Initially you need to catch the '#' key being pressed and then capture the subsequent key presses and pass them to a function to handle your auto completion requirements. A rough outline to of the code is below. You may need to catch whitespace key presses as well to stop the auto-completion.

```
var hashKeyPressed = false;

$('#TextArea').keyup(function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == '222') {
        // this will catch the '#' key
        hashKeyPressed = true;
    }
    if(hashKeyPressed) {
        // Here you can start build up subsequent key presses into a string
        // and pass them to a function to handle the auto-completion
    }
});
```

Comment: How would this work if a user were to amend an existing hash tag? Or say they got halfway through typing a hash tag and realise they spelt something wrong and pressed delete to change it.